# Change SwiftUI @State variable in .onChange(of:) doesn't work

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `NavigationView` with the following code inside:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello"), tag: "A", selection: $jumpToDetail) { }
```

The state variable is defined as:

```
@State var jumpToDetail: String? = nil
```

To test it out I can successfully run this:

```
.onAppear {
  jumpToDetail = "A"
}
```

But when setting the state variable like this, the navigation does *not* happen:

```
.onChange(of: modelData.performJump) { performJump in
  if performJump != nil {
    print("trigger")
    jumpToDetail = "A"
  }
}
```

I do get the "trigger" log message, but the destination view of the `NavigationLink` is not shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use .task(id:) it is more stable

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by switching to `NavigationStack` and path based navigation:

```
@State var navigationPath = [String]()

// ...

NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {

  // ...

}
.onChange(of: modelData.jumpToDetail) { jumpToDetail in
  if let jumpToDetail = jumpToDetail {
    navigationPath = [jumpToDetail]
    modelData.jumpToDetail = nil
  }
}
```